# C# .NET TFS Api: Why is the query request returning "Bug Work Items" without any description value?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

Do you know why when I run a query and the returned item is of "Bug" type, its description will be always null?

PS: It works for User Stories, Tasks, so I thought it should work for Bugs

```
WorkItemCollection wiCollection = workItemStore.Query("wiql");

                foreach (WorkItem wi in wiCollection) //if "wi" is a Bug 
                {

                       string desc = wi.Description; //this value will be null

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. However, there are something different of the "description" between the Bug workitem and other user stories , tasks.

The real "description"  of bug work item is stored in different field which called **Repro Steps**. More details, please see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd997882.aspx) from MSDN.